# Circle Pack Layout minimum radius

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I have a Pack layout, in which some entities have a value of zero.
I'm trying to find a way to set a default radius for those. According to the doc, I was hoping I could write something like this

```
pack.radius(function(r){
   return r==0 ? MIN_RADIUS : oldRadiusFunction(r);
});
```

But haven't had any success so far in identifying how to access "oldRadiusFunction".

The closest I've come to solving this was by doing:

```
pack.radius(function(r){
  return r== 0 ? MIN_RADIUS : p.radius(null)(r);
});
var p = this.pack;
```

... in order to access this.pack from within the function. This seem to work well initially, but starts yielding weird results when I start updating the chart.

Anyway, any help would be much appreciated, thanks a lot for your attention and input !

Edit: Here's what the docs say

> ## pack.radius([radius])
>
> If radius is specified, sets the radius function for computing the radius of each node. If radius is null, as it is by default, the radius is determined automatically from the node value, scaled to fit the layout size. If radius is not specified, returns the current radius function, which defaults to null. The radius can also be specified as a constant number for uniform circle size.

My goal (could be a bit naïve) is to pass a function that would return MIN_RADIUS when passed 0 as an argument, or return what the default would have returned for other values.

Comment: You'll have to give us more context here. What is `oldRadiusFunction` and where is it defined? How do you get "weird" results?

Comment: I don't know what `oldRadiusFunction` is, that's exactly what I'm looking for :)...And I get weird results as soon as I start updating the entities values

Comment: Could you give a complete example? I can't tell you what your radius function should be without an idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'd like oldRadiusFunction to return what pack.radius would have returned if I hadn't altered it. Thanks for your help !

Comment: The default is `Math.sqrt(d.value)`, but that won't help you when the value is 0.

Comment: If I don't call pack.radius(...) or if I call it passing null pack.radius(null), I'll get a radius of zero for entities that have a value of zero. What I'd like is a radius of 40px (for example) instead.

Comment: I did find a reference to Math.sqrt in the pack.js source, but haven't managed to use it to my advantage. I did try doing something like `pack.layout(function(r){return r==0 ? 40 : Math.sqrt(r)); }`, but no luck (I would actually have been surprised)

Comment: It would really help to see a complete example. I don't know what your data looks like and what `r` is in this context.

Comment: r is the (only) parameter passed by d3 to the function I set for pack.radius. It is the entities' value, as returned by the function set for pack.value(). In my case, it can be any number between zero and millions.

Comment: Ok, so when you say "no luck", what do you mean? What happens and what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Well, I get completely out of scale radii. Which makes complete sense: I'm not very good at calculating square roots, but I wouldn't really expect the square root of say 3 millions, to fit in my 500x500px chart :)

Comment: Why are you using the `sqrt` function then? It sounds like a scale would be better here.

Comment: sqrt never really made sense, but I tried it at some point out of desperation ;) All I'm trying to do is to give a minimum radius to circles with no children and no explicit value. How would you tackle that?

Comment: Something like `var scale = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([min, max]).range([minRadius, maxRadius]);` and then `function(r) { return condition ? minRadius : scale(r); }`.

Comment: Excellent, this is really helpful. The radii are still off, but I guess this is just a matter of finding the right values for my scale's domain and range. Say I have a chart of 400x400px, displaying 2 entities, one with a value of 100, another with a value of 200, how would you define the scale above?

Comment: Something like `.domain([100, 200]).range([100, 200])`.

Comment: Why 100 as min value for range?

Comment: Completely arbitrary. Again, I have no idea what you're using this for.

Comment: Rah, I'm still very confused, sorry :)

Comment: Let's say my chart is 500x500px. My data contains 3 items, one with a value of zero (A), one with a value of 200 (B), and the 3rd with a value of 100 (C). What I'd like to display is 3 bubbles, one (A) measuring 40px, the 2 others calculated radii, proportional to their value. Something like http://d.pr/i/Fz7S, hoping this helps?

Comment: `function(r) { return r == 0 ? 40 : scale(r); }` with a scale like above.

Comment: `var scale = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([100,200]).range([0,250])` ? This results in something like http://d.pr/i/QYRZ - As you can see the circle for B (value:100) gets a radius of zero. Shouldn't the domain go from 0 to the sum of all children's values?

Comment: Actually, I seem to be getting "decent" results using a linear scale: `d3.scale.linear().domain([0,sumOfAllChildrenValues]).range(0,chartSize/2)`. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: The scales map the first input to the first output value. So for the scale you've defined, 100 is mapped to 0. If you want the smallest radius to be 40, specify that as the lower end of the range.